# gxt text area programatically scroll down not working

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I'm trying to set an text to text area and to scroll it to bottom, and the following code seems to not work..

```
    TextArea logTextArea = new TextArea();
    logTextArea.setValue(result , true, true);
    final int scrollHeight = logTextArea.getElement().getFirstChildElement().getScrollHeight();
    logTextArea.getElement().getFirstChildElement().setScrollTop(scrollHeight);
```

Tried also another examples with setCursorPos(), also not working. What is wrong with this example?

Comment: Are you sure that textarea is a first child element? Next one works for me (GWT 2.8.2): InputElement textAreaElement = logTextArea.getCell().getInputElement(logTextArea.getElement());
        textAreaElement.setScrollTop(textAreaElement.getScrollHeight());

Comment: Your code worked for me, thanks! So the problem was that it wasn't first child?

Comment: Yes, textarea element is not first child of the TextArea widget element. The DOM structure of the TextArea widget looks like: <widget div> -> <wrapper div> -> <textarea>. But it may depends on appearance that is used.